# DELETE row based on the column value

Tags: sql, excel, oracle11g

Is there a way for me to delete rows based on the value it contains?
For example,
I have a table with values in one column containing a URL value, for example,

/uk/quitclock/om2.asp

/uk/quitclock/om666.wav

Here, I need to delete rows with suffixes ending with WAV, GIF, or JPEG. How do I do that? If it's not possible, then is there any formula in excel that can help me do it?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try this on Database

```
DELETE FROM TABLE 
WHERE UPPER(COLUMN) LIKE '%.WAV' 
      OR UPPER(COLUMN) LIKE '%.GIF' 
      OR UPPER(COLUMN) LIKE '%.JPEG'
```

Answer (score 1):

for excel:

=OR(RIGHT(A1,3)="wav",RIGHT(A1,3)="gif",RIGHT(A1,4)="jpeg")

delete the TRUEs