# Delete from database SQL thinks value is column name

Tags: sql, sql-server

I want to delete all rows that match certain criteria.

Using this syntax [DELETE row based on the column value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13888743/delete-row-based-on-the-column-value)

I wrote:

```
DELETE FROM us_TEST 
    WHERE cell =  "USW00024061"
```

But it says:

> Invalid column name 'USW00024061'.

Even though `cell` is actually the column name.

Answer (score 2):

Use single quotes for string literals:

```
DELETE FROM us_TEST 
    WHERE cell =  'USW00024061'
```